# AWS NET CORE Lambda CICD failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild, aws-secrets-manager

I had follow this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/automated-ci-cd-pipeline-for-net-core-lambda-functions-using-aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli/ to learn how to construct the CICD for dot net core lambda api. However the codebuild keep on trigger the error at the DOWNLOAD_SOURCE phase with the message :Secrets Manager Error: The json key does not exist in this secret. I have no idea what is the reason being for this. All steps mentioned in this article was exactly the same like what I have in the codepipeline.

Comment: Have you double checked the secret manager secrets and their use in CodeBuild? Maybe some spelling mistake somewhere?

Comment: Do you fix this error? Or know what is this error?